# How to locate the below input tag in selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am trying to locate the below WebElement and I am not able to resolve this :

```html
<input class="domain flat ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter city, country or region" autocomplete="off"/>
```

I had tried the following:
**driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class^='domain']"))**

Error : org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[class^='domain']"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make you script to wait for element to be loaded in the DOM.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input.domain")));
```

Comment: Thanks @Sudharsan. Working properly. Though I did use a Thread.sleep() call for 9 seconds (which is not the recommended way), I had problems in locating the webElement. But now, it does gets itself identified :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following selectors :

XPATH:
    //*[contains(@class,'ui-autocomplete-input')]

CSS:
    input[class~='domain']